# Laravel 7 Missing `httpOnly` Cookie Attribute

Tags: laravel, pci-compliance, httponly

I scan my application using PCI Scanner from Clone-system.
It show 1 vulnerabilities -> Missing `httpOnly` Cookie Attribute.

This is the report
https://i.stack.imgur.com/00tc3.jpg

This is my session.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [
   
    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),
    'expire_on_close' => false,
    'encrypt' => false,
    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
    'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION', null),
    'table' => 'sessions',
    'store' => env('SESSION_STORE', null),
    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),

    'path' => '/',

   'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),


    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', true),

    'http_only' => true,

    'same_site' => 'lax',

];
```

I also add some code inside .env

```
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=true
SESSION_HTTP_ONLY=true
```

but no luck , the scanner still say that my application **Missing httpOnly Cookie Attribute.** Attribute.
Can any one guide me how to fix this ? THank you !

Comment: You will get the answer here [Missing HTTPOnly Cookie Attribute in Laravel 7](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/232377/missing-httponly-cookie-attribute-in-laravel-7)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same doubt. Therefore, I created [a discussion in the `laravel/framework` repository](https://github.com/laravel/framework/discussions/48610#discussioncomment-7180262).

The Laravel maintainer `valorin`’s answer will be useful for your question:

> Automated security scanners are ignorant of implementation details like this, so although they work really well for finding low-hanging fruit, they also find things that look like security risks, but really aren't.
> I'm a penetration tester, so I'm always seeing this popup in scanners and I advise my clients to ignore it.